# advanced-http: "data" option is configured to support only following data types: object

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, capacitor, ionic-native

in ionic 5 (capacitor 3 , angular 12) project , i used ionic-native/http for send http request.
when use http.post for send FormData object to server

```
var fd = new FormData();
fd.append('mobile', mobile); 
this.http.post(url,fd,{})
```

show this error:

```
advanced-http: "data" option is configured to support only following data types: object
```

pleas help me.

extra explain: I had to use ionic-native/http. because when i used angular http-client , cancelled post methode and research it and i realized the problem of ssl certificate,
set this code:

```
this.http.setServerTrustMode("nocheck")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
import { HTTP } from '@ionic-native/http/ngx';

constructor(public http: HTTP){}

nativeAPIRequest(){

let params = {
        app_version: '',
        device_id: '',
        community_id: '',
        page_no: '',
        results_per_page: '',
      }

   const options = {
      method: method, // 'GET/POST'
      data: params, // Post Method Parameter
      headers: {}, // 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'auth_token':''
      responseType: 'json' as 'json',
      timeout: 100.0
    };

  this.http.sendRequest(url, options).then(success => {}).catch(async error => {});
}
```

Comment: thanks for response , but when use this, error ```Error: advanced-http: "data" option is configured to support only following data types: Object
    at Object.processData (register-form:3454)
    at Object.sendRequest (register-form:4050)
    at callCordovaPlugin (common.js:235)
    at common.js:48
    at common.js:8
    at new ZoneAwarePromise (zone.js:1340)
    at tryNativePromise (common.js:7)
    at getPromise (common.js:26)
    at wrapPromise (common.js:31)
    at common.js:321```

Comment: @HadiJoghataei i update my answer please check added `params` as a object

Comment: In fact, I wanted to use FormData to send the file object to the server with another parameter.Because of this, I can not use your suggested method and I have to use FormData which gives error. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

The one thing missing from Ravi Ashara response is:

```
this.http.setDataSerializer("urlencoded");
```

> urlencoded: send data as url encoded content in body (content type "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")

https://projetos.imd.ufrn.br/geraldojrcg/iziContatosMySql/tree/master/plugins/cordova-plugin-advanced-http

This what I have:

```
import { HTTP } from '@ionic-native/http/ngx';

export class TokenService {
  constructor(public http: HTTP){}

  public getTokenData(): Observable {
    this.http.setDataSerializer("urlencoded");
    const httpCall = this.http.post(url, {
      "grant_type": "client_credentials",
      ...
    }, {});
    
    return from(httpCall).pipe(
      map(response => {
        if (response.status === 200) {
          return JSON.parse(response.data);
        } else {
          return response;
        }
      })
    );
  }
}
```